# Weird LCD / Boot problems on my MacBook Pro Late 2011

Tags: macos, mac, startup

My Mac is a **MacBook Pro Late 2011** model with the 15 inch screen.

It began all with me, connecting my **Nexus 5** to the Macbook. I imported some videos with iTunes (yes, iTunes popped up automatically and I though I just give it a try). In the import process, the mac suddenly hung up and gave me a gray screen! I then restarted the mac and since then, I have these strange LCD problems on the boot up and crashes as well in normal operation. *I never had any problems with my mac so far, so it must have something to do with me connecting my nexus to my mac!*.

**The Problem**

It's not reproducible for me but sometimes when I boot my mac, some strange lines appear on the LCD and after that, the mac hangs up (all I can see is a gray screen with no content). The mac also gets very loud at that moment. I have to restart and try it over and over again until I can finally login.

Picture of the boot-screen (I zoomed intentionally so you can see the lines):

[image]

Then, sometimes in normal operation, my mac freezes and the lcd displays the same lines as shown above (but with other colors: sometimes just blue, sometimes red and blue etc.). I also can provoke a crash when I connect my **Thunderbolt Display** to the thunderbolt port. But this does not cause a crash everytime **AND** sometimes it just crashes with no monitor connected to it.

What I tried so far:

- Make the apple hardware test (normal and extended) --> no failures were detected.
- Make a clean install of OSX 10.10.3.
- Restetted NVRAM and SMC. (both before and after clean installation)
- Changed the internal storage from an SSD to the original HDD from apple.

None of it solved the issue.

Additional Informations:

- EtreCheck report: http://pastie.org/private/jvogbqnurymvffvzbslxsq
- Currently installed OSX Version: 10.10.4
- Used SSD: Samsung SSD 840 PRO Series (256GB)
- Used Trim Enabler for the SSD (now known as `Disk Sensei`)
- I have **currently no** kernel extensions installed.
- This message appears **on every boot** (in SUM):

`AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::checkStatus - received Status Packet, Payload 2: device was reinitialized`

- Restoring the mac over the internal recovery partition did not work.
- Restoring the mac over the air did also not work.
- Today, /sbin/fsck -fy failed on the startup and I had to repair the volume (Maybe the SSD is damaged?).
- I'm also experiencing kernel panics. Sample log: http://pastie.org/private/i5j5cuv0isb9ttjnllia
- Nexus system informations:

  - Android Version: 5.1.1
  - Kernel Version: 3.4.0
  - The nexus is not modded in any way.

Just got another crash with a new type of failure:

Here is a screenshot of the single user mode after the crash: (note the green lines in the background)

[image]

Comment: Im sorry what did you meant?

Comment: Run the Apple Hardware Test to check your hardware.

Comment: I did (normal and extended) no failures were detected.

Comment: OK, then run this system profile check that might tell us more: http://www.etresoft.com/etrecheck

Comment: OK, here are the results: http://pastie.org/private/jvogbqnurymvffvzbslxsq

Comment: Instead of single user mode try the Verbose mode to see where it gets stuck. I would also do the disk permissions repair and disk check. Since you have kernel panics without 3d party app installed it could be your hardware ...com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement ? and com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor ?

Comment: OK, disk check and repair succeeded (no failures in the disk), now trying the verbose mode!

Comment: Thanks, maybe this solved the issue. I will do the verbose boot if it happens again and then post the log.

Comment: Nope, didnt work. Sadly, the verbose mode does not show where the mac gets stuck ;(

Comment: I noticed you reset the NVRAM but did you try a PRAM reset? [Instructions here.](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18761?locale=en_US)

Comment: scary, but it looks like the logic bard failures based on log: com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement  and com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably caused by the famous GPU problem these MacBook have. Do a search on Google for Late 2011 MacBook GPU problems and you will find loads of information about this. Apple finally recognized the manufacturing error and has a program in place to replace the logic board under warranty. 
I had mine replaced a couple months ago with no costs at all.

Comment: Yep, did go to an apple store and they replaced it.

Comment: Nice!! Glad to be of help!!

Comment: Did you have any problems after replacing the logic board? Heard you should make a gpu stress test to verify the replacement.

Comment: No, i didn't do a GPU test. I just use the MBP as i did before and it behaves as it did before. I guess they replaced the logic board with an identical one. So i suspect we will have the same issue again in a couple of years. These GPUs just get way too hot.

Comment: It's 6 years later now and the replacement board also broke. Unfortunately no warranty anymore so i disabled the GPU using these instructions: https://gist.github.com/cdleon/d1eff7246a25193304284ecec40445b0

Comment: There is another very detailed instruction here on stackexchange to use the internal GPU without overheating (software solution): https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295805/117930